# Terrarium-like agent interaction framework

Tags: frameworks, simulation, agent

I'm looking for a framework for agent interaction simulation, where I can deploy some agents and let them interact and watch their evolution.

Until now I found Terrarium 2.0 (http://terrarium2.codeplex.com/). In principle this is what I need: the ability to create some creature/agent and deploy it into a simulation framework where it will interact with other agents. But it seems that Terrarium is no longer under development.

Do you know of any similar frameworks which are worth considering?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to see Terrarium for VS 2010 myself. It's not under development anymore, but the source is released and is still functional. So I guess it can be updated and expanded if anyone has the time, I would if I had :) The [public server is still online](http://www.terrariumserver.com/), but there are no peers online. Don't know of any similar frameworks, for .Net at least.